# Django show image/video which is outside of static folder

Tags: python, html, django, web, path

I want to make web site which show file tree in web and print image/video on web.
I'm planning to print it with html tag `img` and `video`. However there are some problems with path. Most of my static files( like video or img) outside of django project folder.
For example django template source and view source is at `/Users/Knight/My-site/Damotorie_cafe/views.py` and image is at `/Applications/MAMP/practice`
I tried to get relative path with python code and use it for src attribute.
Same path works well when I don't use django and just open it with local web browser, however when I open it with django then error occur.

I'm starter in django. Can any one help me?
(I searched it before asking, but most of question is about upload not show image.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your static files in Django.  In the settings.py, you need to set up:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/path/to/your/images/outside/web/tree/'
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In development, you need to set this in your base urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    ...
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Then in your template files, first set this at the top of the template file, so you load the 'static' tag:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Then you use the static variable:

```
<img src="{% static 'path/img' %}"/>
```

The trick is, Django searches through STATICFILES_DIRS to find that 'path' in your template file, so the end 'path' has to be different from anything you have in your other listed STATICFILES_DIRS.  It searches the list in order, and will find the first one that matches, in any event.